# get UIImage from sender in swift

Tags: swift, casting, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a `UIImageView` inside a table cell and I added a tapGesture to it.
I want to access the `UIImageView` in the handleTap method.

This is the code for the Image inside the TableCell :

```
func setImageForCell(cell:ImageCell, indexPath:NSIndexPath) {
    var image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "brunnen1")!

    cell.customImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.imageView!.tag = indexPath.row;
    var tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("handleTap:"))
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    cell.customImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    cell.customImageView.image = image
}


func handleTap(sender : UIView) {
    // get the UIImageview from the sender, i guess ?

}
```

I guess I have to cast it from the `UIView`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code.

```
func handleTap(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let imgView = sender.view as! UIImageView
    // Do something.
}
```

Since you use a gesture recognizer, `handleTap`'s sender will be `UITapGestureRecognizer`. The gesture recognizer has what you want.

> `var view: UIView? { get }` // the view the gesture is attached to. set by adding the recognizer to a UIView using the addGestureRecognizer: method

Answer (score 0):

No, the `sender` is a `UITapGestureRecognizer` not `UIView`. You should do this:

```
func handleTap(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let imageView = sender.view as! UIImageView
}
```